# Interfaces for fluent ordered constructor

Tags: c#, interface, constructor, fluent

iam creating an interface for a fluent ordered constructor and i have wrote this code:

```
public interface IMyObjectFactory: IObjectWithProperty
{
  int objectId { get; set; }
  IObjectWithProperty WithObjectId(int id);
}

public interface IObjectWithProperty
{
  IObjectWithProperty WithObjectId(int id);
  MyObject Create();
}
```

the second interface is need to enforce order in constructor method

the impl is this:

```
public class MyObjectFactory: IMyObjectFactory
{
    public int objectId { get; set; }
    private MyObjectFactory() { }
    public static IObjectWithProperty BeginCreation()
    {
        return new ObjectFactory();
    }
    public IObjectWithProperty WithObjectId(int id)
    {
        objectId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public MyObject Create()
    {
        return new MyObject(this);
    }
}
```

And this is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public MyObject(IMyObjectFactory factory)
  {
    this.Id = factory.objectId;
  }
}
```

so I can write

```
MyObject mo = MyObjectFactory.BeginCreation().WithObjectId(1).Create();
```

but:

- I have to define property both in interface and impl of the constructor and don't like much
- the static BeginCreation method has no interface
- I have to set public the impl property while i want it internal
- in the interface i get this warning: `Warning    7   'FunzIA.DL.Factory.Interfaces.IMyObjectFactory.WithObjectId(int)' hides inherited member 'FunzIA.DL.Factory.Interfaces.IObjectWithProperty.WithObjectId(int)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

but is not a new method and i need the second interface to enforce order

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Why excatly you need the same method in `WithObjectId`? You get it through inheritance.

Comment: to exclude this use: MyObjectFactory.WithObjectId(1), it enforce that you must first call BeginCreation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in this way:

- simply don't want to let class constructor to be visible, i want only the factory to be accessible

```
public interface IMyObjectFactory: IObjectWithProperty
{
  int objectId { get; set; }
}

public interface IObjectWithProperty
{
  IObjectWithProperty WithObjectId(int id);
  MyObject Create();
}

public class MyObjectFactory: IMyObjectFactory
{
  public int objectId;
  private MyObjectFactory() { }

  public static IObjectWithProperty BeginCreation()
  {
    return new MyObjectFactory();
  }

  public IObjectWithProperty WithObjectId(int id)
  {
    objectId = id;
    return this;
  }

  public MyObject Create()
  {
    return new MyObject(this);
  }
}

public class MyObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public MyObject(IMyObjectFactory factory)
  {
    this.Id = factory.objectId;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyObjectFactory: IMyObjectFactory
{
  private int objectId;
  private MyObjectFactory() { }

  public static IObjectWithProperty BeginCreation()
  {
    return new ObjectFactory();
  }

  public IObjectWithProperty WithObjectId(int id)
  {
    objectId = id;
    return this;
  }

  public MyObject Create()
  {
    return new MyObject(objectId);
  }
}

public class MyObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public MyObject(int objectId)
  {
    this.Id = objectId;
  }
}
```

My opinion:

- You can remove `WithObjectId` in `IMyObjectFactory`. You get it through inheritance. This setup is the reason for the warnings you get.
- `BeginCreation` is fine where it is. At some point you have to create real world objects and that is not possible just with interfaces. You need real classes.
- I would never let `MyObject` know about any factories. Factories know and create objects, not the other way around. `Create` should construct `MyObject`. This also results in not having the need to have the `objectId` property (which you do not like anyway).

Comment: WithObjectId removed: i extract the inteface from the impl that contains the second interface and make some confusion

Comment: I don't want to let other class be able to create object without factory but i like the idea to call the object constructor: in this way who call the object see that he must use factory

Comment: Other question: is right to use interface for constructor or is bettere to move versus abstract factory?

Comment: Depends. You might want to make the object class at least internal, have an object interface. Thus making everybody go through the fluent interface of the factory. If you need that.

Comment: no, public object is ok, i want to protect only the creation part so that the instance is make only with all the needed parameter. i use fluent only for avoid having constructor with many parameters (in the example is only one but in real case is many more)

Comment: so simply don't want the standard class contructor and create the one that accept factory as parameter

Comment: But then you need more public information on the factory. Which is not ideal.

Comment: ? In my project object and factory are stable and without different implementation, so i dont see the problem in object knowing how its make: the only scope of factory is to make object creation more readable and eventually testable